# How does vectors multiply act in shader language?

Tags: opengl

Such as `gl_FragColor = v1 * v2`, i can't really get how does it multiplies and it seems that the reference give the explanation of vector multiply matrix.
ps: The type of `v1` and `v2` are both `vec4`.

Comment: [Here's how.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_of_vectors)

Comment: @H2CO3 the actual operation performed is not even listed there.

Comment: @KillianDS It is. Scalar (dot) product.

Comment: That is the definition of the dot product. The question is about the effect of the * operator on vectors in GLSL. The answer is that * represents a component wise multiplication

Comment: @user529758 GLSL `vecN * vecN` is NOT scalar dot product.

Comment: Dot product returns a scalar. `vecN * vecN` results in a `vecN`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `*` operator works [component-wise](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations#Operators) for vectors like `vec4`.

```
vec4 a = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
vec4 b = vec4(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4);
vec4 c = a * b; // vec4(0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 1.6)
```

The [GLSL Language Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.30.6.pdf) says under section *5.10 Vector and Matrix Operations*:

> With a few exceptions, operations are component-wise. Usually, when an
>   operator operates on a vector or matrix, it is operating independently
>   on each component of the vector or matrix, in a component-wise
>   fashion. [...] The exceptions are matrix multiplied by vector, vector
>   multiplied by matrix, and matrix multiplied by matrix. These do not
>   operate component-wise, but rather perform the correct linear
>   algebraic multiply.

Comment: So it just does the dot product?

Comment: @user674199: No, the result of a scalar (=dot) product is a scalar. The result of the `*` GLSL operator on vectors is a vector again. You can make a scalar product out of it, by adding the vector components after the componentwise multiplication. But if you actually need a scalar product, GLSL offers the builtin function `dot`.

Comment: Here is a [ShaderToy program](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xs23zV) that illustrates that the multiplication is indeed component-wise.

Comment: This operation is also known as "Hadamard product": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Comment: @FrankCheng In GLSL, doing `vec4 c = a * b;` is the same as doing `vec4 c; c.x = a.x * b.x; c.y = a.y * b.y; c.z = a.z * b.z; c.w = a.w * b.w;`.  That's what component-wise means— each component of the vector is treated as an algebraic value, ignoring the other components.  It may be easier to rationalize if you consider what happens on silicon— a vec4 * vec4 multiplication isn't a mathematical or geometric vector; its simply 4 float values that are independently multiplied by 4 other float values, computed in parallel.

Comment: @FrankCheng Because of this, people doing extreme shader optimizations will sometimes lump unrelated data into `vec4`s just so they can get parallelization speedup when doing algebraic operations.  __TL;DR: To GLSL and the GPU, a `vec4` doesn't mean anything specific mathematically/geometrically; it's just 4 floats one right after the other in memory.__  _(In programming environments where vectors have intrinsic mathematic meanings, you instead see types like `point3`, `normal3`, `offset3`, `velocity3`, `accel3`, etc.)_

Comment: Why is not standard and is called Hadarmard Product Had(), just as Dot and Cross. that would immediately answer most questions.

Comment: I'm not sure calling it the Hadamard Product would answer more questions than it raised, to be honest. While that's what it's often called, the number of people who know their Khatri–Rao from their Kroneker, from their Hadamard products are probably rather small.