# Computing a pixel's specular value?

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, rgb, raytracing

I've been looking around the internet to get the formula for computing's the diffuse value of a given pixel in a raytracer (where a ray intersection has occurred of course).

The examples I found all involve multiplying colours by other colours. Nvidia's formula is as follows:

```
diffuse = Kd x lightColor x max(N · L, 0)
```

where:

```
- Kd is the material's diffuse color
- lightColor is the color of the incoming diffuse light
- N is the normalized surface normal
- L is the normalized vector toward the light source
- P is the point being shaded
```

The formula doesn't seem too hard to me, but when trying to program it I find that `Kd x lightColour` is the multiplication of 2 RGB values. This is confusing to me as, unless it's a case of just multiplying both R, G and B values together, there's no way to multiply values like this.

Similarly, the specular formula requires the RGB value to be raised to a power equivalent to the shininess factor of the material, which is again a multiplication of a 3-component data type by itself.

This is probably me just getting confused with the maths, but if someone could clear this up it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kd x lightColour is a component-wise multiplication:

```
  a       d       a*d
[ b ] x [ e ] = [ b*e ]
  c       f       c*f
```

In the formula for specular illumination (assuming you are talking about the [phong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model) or blinn-phong illumination model), there is no power operation on vectors.

```
specular = ks x lightcolor x (R · V)^a
```

The result of `R · V` is a float, thus the power is only applied to a single number.

Comment: A short comment on mathematical notation. The componentwise multiplication of vectors is called the "Hadamard Product" and usually is denoted by a unfilled circle `○ ` (keep in mind that the same symbol is also used for function composition).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901119/how-does-vectors-multiply-act-in-shader-language